# Not sure how to write connect by clause

Tags: oracle, hierarchical-data, connect-by

I have the following query to find employees who are not managers in the EMP table of oracle

```
 select * from emp e1
 where not exists (select null from emp e2 
                    where e2.mgr=e1.empno)
```

I need output using start with connect by clause , thus avoiding self join

Comment: `connect by` is for hierarchical queries.  For instance, we might use it to display a family connected as Grandparent, Parent, Child.   What is the hierarchy in this requirement?

Comment: Ok let me make it simple, I have

Comment: select empno,mgr,ename||' works for '|| prior ename "Employees and their Managers"
  From emp
  where mgr is not null
  start with  mgr is null
  connect by prior empno = mgr

Comment: I just want to have output like "Employee Turner is not a manager"

Answer (score 1):

There is a function, CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF(), which indicates whether a given row in a hierarchical query is a leaf node.  In the EMP table, employees who are not managers will be leaf nodes.

So, we can use this function in a nested hierarchical query to filter the non-managers:

```
select empno, mgr, ename 
from (
    select empno, mgr, ename, CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF cbi
    from emp 
    start with mgr is null 
    connect by prior empno = mgr
) where cbi = 1
/
```

Oracle has several neat functions for interrogating hierarchies.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries003.htm#SQLRF52332).

Comment: Wow as always you guys rock!!